# why my java code fails when i'm trying to typecast inside try block?

Tags: java, try-catch, division, typecasting-operator

I've written the code this way where the method division returns double value after dividing two integers.It works fine if i do not include try catch block.But when I enclose the integer division with type casting inside try block as shown below, it leads to compilation problem... please solve my problem.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Division {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        Division div=new Division();
        System.out.println("Enter the two numbers to perform division operation:");
        int x=sc.nextInt();
        int y=sc.nextInt();
        div.division(x,y);
    }

    public double division(int x,int y){
        try{
            double z=(double)(x/y);
            return z;
            }
        catch(ArithmeticException ae){
            ae.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you must add the `return` statement after the try-catch block to return a default value, if exception occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Your method must have a `return` statement.

Your current code don't have `return` statement if it enters the `catch` block.

Try this code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Division {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Division div = new Division();
        System.out.println("Enter the two numbers to perform division operation:");
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        int y = sc.nextInt();
        div.division(x, y);
    }

    public double division(int x, int y) {
        double z = 0;
        try {
            z = (double) (x / y);
        } catch (ArithmeticException ae) {
            ae.printStackTrace();
        }
        return z;
    }

}
```

Live Demo [**`here`**](http://ideone.com/V8DLvY).

Also I guess there is data loss in the way you are type-casting.
If `17/3 = 5.6666666` is what you want, then your code is **WRONG** because `x` and `y` are `int`. The output you will get with the current code is `17/3=5`

Instead of <strike>`z = (double) (x / y);`</strike>, you need **`z = (double) x / (double) y;`**

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a return in your division function. By catching the exception you are saying that you are going to do something to handle it in the case that there is an issue and execution will continue after.

It would probably be best to just throw the exception here because if you divide by zero there will be nothing to return. Optionally you could return something nonsensical like -1

```
public double division(int x,int y){
    try{
        double z=(double)(x/y);
        return z;
        }
    catch(ArithmeticException ae){
        ae.printStackTrace();
    }
    return -1;
}
```

An even better solution would be to throw an exception if the divisor is 0 and then handle it wherever it is used

```
public double division(int x, int y) throws ArithmeticException {
        if (y == 0)
            throw new ArithmeticException("Cannot divide by 0");
        double z = (double) (x / y);
        return z;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method missing the `return` statement. Try this one

```
 public double division(int x,int y){
        double z=0.0;
        try{
             z=(double)(x/y);

        }
        catch(ArithmeticException ae){
            ae.printStackTrace();
        }
        return z;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that if your try block fails, there's no return statement found (since the return you provided was local only to the try block).

So as others have pointed out, you could either return something (e.g. -1) **outside** both the try and the catch blocks (*but still inside the method*),
 or you could have a return statement in the catch block as well, so even if the try throws an exception, your method still returns a double.